# Retrieve a key-value data structure from MariaDB query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I would like to do a query to retrieve a key-value data structure without putting the burden on the code. 
For example, if I have the following query:

```
SELECT id, nome FROM articolo
```

is there a way in mariaDB to throw this data into a key-value data structure so you don't do it from code and do it directly from query? Something like:

```
SELECT {id: nome} FROM articolo
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [JSON functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-functions/).

This creates an object for each row:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(id, nome) FROM articolo;
```

If you want all the values in a single object, use:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(id, nome) FROM articolo
```

Comment: Very elegant as a solution, but it gives me only one entry in the json.

Comment: Updated to show how to aggregate them all into one JSON.

Comment: I got the following error: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION tuttle.JSON_OBJECTAGG does not exist` "tuttle" is the name of my DB.

Comment: The function was added in MariaDB 10.5.0.